# How can I force the Synergy server to use a specific IP address?

Tags: synergy

My workstation has several network adapters, some virtual, some physical.  One of them is the Bridged Network Adapter from one of my Virtual Machines.  For some reason Synergy always chooses that adapters IP, even though without the VirtualBox adapter there it worked perfectly on the original physical adapter.  The result is that it's tied to a virtual bridged adapter and can't communicate on the network with the intended machines running the Synergy Client.

**How can I force the Synergy Server to utilize a specific IP address?** Is this setting available if I manually edit the conf file? If I can't force the IP, can I force the MAC or Adapter it chooses?

I'm on Synergy 1.7.6, latest as far as I can see.  Both Server and clients are Windows 10 machines.

Comment: Bug thread (over 2 years old and unresolved): https://github.com/symless/synergy/issues/4251

Comment: @isherwood Thanks, but you may notice I've been pretty active in that issue thread... in fact I provided a temporary work around to the problem for those dealing with VM related scenarios.

Comment: It was for the benefit of the community, and you'd do us a service by incorporating the link into your question.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the solution, but it is the correct "answer" for you as far as I can see.  According to Symless, the issue will not be resolved until Synergy 2.0, which "should be released in a few months." (As of 6/23/17.) This information comes from their Twitter account in response to a user who asked the same question as you did.

Per the GitHub comments for the publicly available source code, this issue has persisted for over two years.

Answer (score -2):

A "solution" would be to change the IPV4 address of the computer you have the server running on. i.e. My desktop's local i.p. is 192.168.0.173 If I changed that to 192.168.0.174 then all the clients would have to be changed to connect to the new address.

Comment: My PC is on a static IP and Synergy still chooses the wrong one sometimes. I either have to change the client config or restart the system.